# Raspbian keyboard shortcuts

Tags: raspbian

Is there a list anywhere of the keyboard shortcuts in Raspbian?  There's nothing obvious in the documentation that I've found.  I've established that Cmd+r opens starts 'run' and Cmd+e opens an explorer window. Are there any others?

Comment: Perhaps one of the more important ones I've found is Alt+Space+M, which allows you to move the current window with the arrow keys... Then hit Enter when finished. Also, Windows + D is to show/hide the desktop.

Comment: I agree - `Alt+Space` shows the window options menu which has all the useful commands. Remember to **press <enter> after doing a move/resize** from it. Also, there's another command for making the active window full-screen, `Alt+F11`, which doesn't appear to be listed in the *openbox* (window manager) options file (see answer below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are using LXDE, the default desktop, you are actually runnig openbox as the window manager.

`grep -A 1 \<keybind /etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` will give you the default ones.

`~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` contains your shortcuts if it exists.

Comment: With `Linux raspberrypi 3.18.11-v7+` the file is: `/home/pi/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml`

Comment: `echo "grep -A 1 \<keybind /etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml" > ShowShortcuts` .................... then do: `. ShowShortcuts`

Comment: A useful answer, thanks. It's important to remember that `C`,`S`,`A` and `W` in the keyboard shortcuts means the Control, Shift, Alt and Windows (meta) keys. Also, adding a space and `| less` to the `echo` string in @Andrew 's command would make it easier to read and work when the script file is opened in a new terminal.

Comment: Before finding this, I was using terminal with the [`xdotool`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/setting-the-window-dimensions-of-a-running-application) command. The tool simulates keyboard/mouse activity and changes windows using the X11 window system. I know that on Raspbian GNU/Linux, there are some general shortcuts like F10, Control+Tab, Control+Alt+F1-F8 but I hadn't found the LXDE desktop window manager (*openbox*) ones.

Comment: (longer) code to create executable script file that opens in terminal: `echo -e '#\!/bin/bash\n# C-ontrol,S-hift,A-lt,W-indows\n# Show Raspbian LXDE desktop keyboard shortcuts (openbox window manager).\n# From a command found on the page <https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9344/raspbian-keyboard-shortcuts>.\ngrep -A 1 \<keybind /etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml | less' > ~/show_desktop_key_shortcuts.sh; chmod +x ~/show_desktop_key_shortcuts.sh`

Answer (score 1):

The configuration file is the lxde-pi-rc.xml that contains different keybind keys. Just add one that you want in this file following the examples.

I found the lxde-pi-rc.xml but in my case it was in a different path: /etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml

I guess that in the recent versions they changed the path.

I hope it can help you.