# How to set keyboard shortcuts

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, keyboard, pixel

How do I setup a keyboard shortcut to run `xscreensaver-command -lock` when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>? I've had a look at [Raspbian keyboard shortcuts](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9344/raspbian-keyboard-shortcuts), but that talks about finding the keyboard shortcuts, not setting them.

Answer (score 12):

I just figured out how to do this. After having a look at `~/.config/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml`. I just duplicated one of the `<keybind>` tags and edited the contents of the tag.

Heres my keybind:

```
<keybind key="A-C-l">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>xscreensaver-command -lock</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

You can find instructions to setup keybinds [here](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings#Key_bindings)

Comment: For those having a newer Raspian version: The path has changed to `/etc/xdg/openbox/lxde-pi-rc.xml`.